# OP getting me to do the work for them over time

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I've answered this question for a new user that wasn't originally worded like a "do my work for me" type of question, but has since turned that way through discussion in the comments.

They have posted a link to their code and asked how they should tweak it, to which I responded with help.

Then they responded with something to the effect of "We're almost there. Just a few more tweaks. Try doing it with something like..."

They're very clearly trying to drag the complete solution out of me. How should I go about dealing with this OP?

Comment: It is a well-known problem at SO.  Type "chameleon question" in the Search box at the upper-right of this page.  Basic strategy is not fall for it.  Rollback the question edits if you have to.  Just ignore when that doesn't work.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to walk away.

Comment: Tell them that you'd be glad to help them for your usual consulting rate of $`X` per hour with a minimum billed time of at least `Y` hours paid up front (where `X >= 100` and `Y >= 2`).

Comment: @UphillLuge, this is not a case "chameleon question", it's an extended "discussion in the comments". No question edit is involved here.

Comment: Chameleon questions are one of the reasons that Stack Exchange seems more and more hostile to me as time goes by.